# Android Set System Setting Font On Webview

Tags: android, fonts, webview

Hi I need to set a Webview font family to the one being used by the rest of the app (The one set in Android > Settings > Font). I thought I would use css to set the font family name to the one set under android settings, but cant seem to get the name of the font family set in android system settings. I'm not sure if this approach would work either but its worth a try. Please help